# how can I check if there is repeated values inputted by user so that the quantity should be incremented

Tags: data-structures, stack

```java
package stack;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        while (true) {
         
            String order = scanner.next();

            if (order.equalsIgnoreCase("OUT")) {
                break;
            }

            boolean isValidItem = isValidMenuItem(order);
            if (isValidItem) {
                stack.push(order);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid item. Please choose from the menu.");
            }
        }
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            int quantity = 0;
            int totalCost = 0;
            
            
            System.out.println(quantity + stack.pop() + totalCost);
        }

        System.out.println("END");
        scanner.close();
    }

    private static boolean isValidMenuItem(String item) {
        String[] menu = {"Cheeseburger $6", "pasta $6", "fries $3", "chicken $20", "soda $2"};
        for (String menuItem : menu) {
            if (menuItem.equalsIgnoreCase(item)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can i chcked stack list so that i can increment quanity.
if inputted : cheeseburger, soda, chicken, cheeseburger. the cheeseburger should incremented.

Comment: Why use a stack?